# Does undirected damage require line of sight/effect?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat

Certain powers cause damage without specifying any conditions about how that damage is dealt. Consider, for example, the following **Barbarian** `Rage` Daily Powers:

> **Earthquake Dragon's Rage**
>   **Effect:** whenever an enemy hits you, you deal thunder damage equal to your strength modifier to each creature within 5 squares of you.

or

> **Desert Wind Rage**
>   **Effect:** at the start of each of your turns, you deal 5 + your strength modifier fire >damage to each enemy within 5 squares of you.

Does the Raging Barbarian need line of sight or line of effect to a target to deal damage to it? For example, if an enemy is on the other side of a wall but within 5 squares, do they take the damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, you still need Line of Effect.**

The damage dealt by these `Rage` effects may not be a close burst attack (or any other type of attack for that matter) but you still require **Line of Effect**.

Rules Compendium p.107:

> **Line of Effect:** Unless otherwise noted, there must be a line of effect from the origin square of an effect and its intended target for that target to be affected.

Note that the rules mention *effects* and not merely *attacks*.